# Layout with 100% height sidebar

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying and filing to create a website that has two sidebars and that both are top to bottom, or header to footer... Whatever I try, it doesn't work, and I don't know why...

It might be some stupid mistake I made, but I have experience in creating websites, but something like this has never happened to me yet.

Here is a link to the Work-in-Progress version: http://dino-praso.stud.ba/aubih/eLearning/

`JSFiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/6Mr48/

Comment: can you provide some of the code that you have so far?

Comment: @aashnisshah There is a link to the complete site in the post...

Comment: External links change, rendering the question useless. Request you to put relevant code in the question.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao well I don't know where the problem is so i would need to paste everything here ? Wouldn't that be too much ?
If you want I will make a fiddle, if that is more helpfull

Comment: @DinoPrašo JSFiddle will be the right thing to do :)

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/6Mr48/

Comment: I swear I encountered this problem years ago, but for the life of me I can't remember how or even if I ever solved it. Two options: [1.] Use javascript. [2.] Make a .gif that's 200px wide and 20px high and the color of your sidebar's background. Set it as the background image for the body with `background-repeat:repeat-y;` I'm deleting the answer I posted now that I know the whole story.

Comment: @Frankenscarf OK. I appreciate your help. I'll try to rebuild it and if that doesn't work, i'll use one of your suggestions.

Comment: See the updated answer below for a 3rd and better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using javascript or using the background image "cheat", consider the code in the fiddle below:

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCgyP/1/)

By placing everything in a "wrapper", whenever the content of your `<section>` extends past the height of your sidebar content, the wrapper `<div>` it is wrapped inside will extend with the `<section>` content. This allows the sidebar, which is also a child of the wrapper div, to make use of 100% in the way you want.

Comment: I know that, but it isn't working... That is what the question is about. Try editing my fiddle and you'll see.

Comment: After walking outside for a break, it all came back to me. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Anytime, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forgot

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
```

for the left side of you page

Comment: for what ? for the sidebar ?